How do I specify table schema in golang?
I encapsulate db rows with a struct
type myThingy {
    col1 string
    col2 int
}

but when writing a query function, I have to type out the name of the column
queryThingy(col1Val string) {
    return db.queryf("SELECT * WHERE col1==%s", col1Val)
}

I would much rather have some sort of const to use instead
queryThingy(colKey string, colVal string) {
    return db.queryf("SELECT * WHERE %s==%s",colKey, colVal)
}

however since I already have myThingy type, I would just like to take the struct field names and turn it into a set of constants that i can use to specify the column names in my db
obviously this is a toy example but the pattern would be useful to me

Is the %s a go placeholder (i.e. passed for fmt.Sprintf) or a mysql (or similar db) parameter? (ideally show us the implementation of db.queryf).

I would use db struct tags. They work similar to json, yaml, etc.
Here's a great lib for it: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.

Maybe you can combine the usage of "struct tags" and "reflection". With those tools you will be able to generate for example a map with the struct field names as a keys and the column names in your database as a value, and then you can use this map to build the query.
For example, to use struct tags you need to do this:
type myThingy {
    col1 string `db_column_name:"column_1"`
    col2 int `db_column_name:"column_2"`
}

After that, you can use reflection to inspect/analyze the fields and tags of your struct (myThingy) at runtime to build the suggested map:
func getColumnNames(myStruct interface{}) map[string]string {
    columns := make(map[string]string)
    valueType := reflect.TypeOf(myStruct)
    for i := 0; i < valueType.NumField(); i++ {
        field := valueType.Field(i)
        if dbTag, ok := field.Tag.Lookup("db_column_name"); ok {
            columns[field.Name] = dbTag
        }
    }
    return columns
}

And to build the query you can do this:
func queryThingy(colKey string, colVal string) string {
    mt := myThingy{}
    columnNames := getColumnNames(mt)
    columnName, _ := columnNames[colKey]
    return fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * WHERE %s=%s", columnName, colVal)
}

You can try this approach in https://go.dev/play/p/4gtnyt0e2aK
Also you can see the following documentation and questions related:

What are the use(s) for struct tags in Go?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-golang/

Additional cosiderations:
If you prefer this approach, remember to account for cases where the tag is missing in a particular field. And to build the query if you are handling sensitive data consider using "prepared statements" to prevent SQL injection.
